# Compact embedding result

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, compactness

Let $\tau$ and $\ell$ be positive numbers. We know that the space $H^2(0,\ell)\cap H^1_0(0,\ell)$ is compactly embedded into $L^6(0,\ell)$. Now, is the space $L^2(0,\tau;H^2(0,\ell)\cap H^1_0(0,\ell))$ compactly embedded into $L^2(0,\tau;L^6(0,\ell))$?

Comment: Well, the space $\mathbb{R}$ embeds compactly into $\mathbb{R}$, but still $L^2(0,\tau;\mathbb{R})$ does not embed compactly into $L^2(0,\tau;\mathbb{R})$, right?